# allowsMultipleSelection in ImagePicker is not working in Expo ( React Native )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pick multiple images in one time but I am not able to select them. I am using Expo ImagePicker and I am passing `allowsMultipleSelection:true` props as true but did not selecting multiple photos . Could someone please help me how to achieve my goal .

Thanks

**Code**

```
 let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            quality: 1,
            allowsMultipleSelection: true,
            base64: false,
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The prop **allowsMultipleSelection** is Web-only:

Ref: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/

Feature Request: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/allow-choosing-multiple-images-in-imagepicker [CLOSED]